# myvector.size() return 0 in a only function

Tags: c++, vector, memory-leaks

_curLevel.size() is the private vector I created in class level, whenever i tries to run .size() function inside getPosition function,it returns 0.But in other function this command works well and returns 13.I found out my for loop isn't working because of it.
I copy the main.cpp and level.h as well.

level.cpp

```
bool level::loadGame(string file_name){
    string line;
    load.open(file_name);
    if (load.fail()){
        cout << "Failed to Load Saved Game" << endl;
        return false;
    }else{
        while ((getline(load, line))){
            _curLevel.push_back(line);
        }
        cout << _curLevel.size() << endl;
        return true;
    }
}
int level::getPosition(char object,char coor){
    char a;
    cout << _curLevel.size() << endl;
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < (_curLevel.size()); y++){
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < (_curLevel[y].size()); x++){
            a = _curLevel[y][x];
            if (object == a){
                switch (coor){
                case 'x':
                    return x;
                case 'y':
                    return y;
                default:
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void level::printLevel(){
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < (_curLevel.size()); i++){
        cout << _curLevel[i] << endl;
    }
    cout << _curLevel.size() << endl;
}
```

level.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class level
{
public:
    level();
    bool loadGame(string file_name);
    int getPosition(char object, char coor);
    /*void saveGame(string file_name);*/
    void printLevel();
    void initLevel();
private:
    vector <string> _curLevel;
    ifstream load;
    ofstream save;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "level.h"
#include "player.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    level level;
    level.loadGame("ha.txt");
    level.printLevel();
    player player;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

player.cpp

```
#include "player.h"
#include "global.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "level.h"

using namespace std;

player::player()
{
    level level;
    _playeryCoor = level.getPosition(playersymbol,'y');
    _playerxCoor = level.getPosition(playersymbol,'x');
    cout << _playeryCoor << endl;
    cout << _playerxCoor << endl;
    cout << "e";
}
```

player.h

```
#pragma once
#include "level.h"
#include <iostream>

class player
{
public:
    player();
private:
    int _playeryCoor;
    int _playerxCoor;
};
```

global.h

```
namespace
{
    char playersymbol = '@';
}
```

ha.txt

```
####################################
#..................................#
#..................................#
#..................................#
#..................................#
#...............@..................#
#..................................#
#..................................#
#..................................#
#..................................#
#..................................#
#..................................#
####################################
```

Comment: You are never calling getPosition in this code.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. Also provide a minimal `ha.txt` sample file

Comment: A part from `player` being undefined, the missing `level::level` constructor and the fact you never call `getPosition`, there is nothing obviously wrong with your code. Are you sure the code you're running is the code you compiled?

Comment: With minimal changes to get it compiling, the code seems to work: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f62c18b62d1be17

Comment: stefaanv thank you i move it to the main.cpp and it works, I also tried to crate a new function in player.cpp, it doesn't work either.is there anyway to get it working in player.cpp

Comment: I removed my comment because it was not the real problem. Are you referring to my  answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the added code of `player`: you declare a local `level` in the constructor of `player`. The `vector` in that local `level` is not filled, so its size is zero.

A possible solution is to pass the global `level` as parameter to the constructor of `player`.

Comment: possible solution: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c0ad923bf0b9271